# How to write regular expression for apt-get so that it excludes package conflicts?

Tags: linux, shell, apt, regular-expression, fonts

I am trying to install all packages that contain `font` in their name. I tried `apt-get install *font*` but packages `fontforge` and `fontforge-nox` conflict each other. How should I revise my regex so that `apt-get` picks up all desired packages except the problematic two?

Comment: You probably want "fonts-*" instead.

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/735457/edit) your question to add a bit more info - it's a bit easier to determine how X should be modified if X can be analyzed :-)